# Why my flex items don't stretch vertically?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a navbar, but not all my `<li>` stretch vertically. Currently only the `<li>` with `<h1>` is fully stretched vertically inside the container but there is white space to the left of it somehow though. The remaining `<li>` have white space above and below them. How do i make them stretch to take all vertical space (centered)?

[Image of the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ1dK.jpg)

```css
body, h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
header ul {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid black;
    align-items: baseline;
}

header ul li {
    background-color: bisque;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jenga Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>homepagio</h1>
      </li>
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        Werk
      </li>
      <li>
        Contact
      </li>
      <li>
        Disclaimer
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body, h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
header ul {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid black;
    align-items: stetch;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header ul li {
    background-color: bisque;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Jenga Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>homepagio</h1>
      </li>
      <li>
        Home
      </li>
      <li>
        Werk
      </li>
      <li>
        Contact
      </li>
      <li>
        Disclaimer
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks better. There is still white space left to the h1, what is this? i have no margin.